# ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting when the default backend "matplotlib" is selected

Tags: python, linux, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-profiling

I am new to pandas_profiling and getting ImportError while importing it. Please help.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
```

After executing the above code in jupyter notebook, I am getting the following error.

ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting when the default backend "matplotlib" is selected.

**> python --version** 
Python 3.7.3

**> pip list | grep -E "matplotlib|pandas"** 
matplotlib                         3.2.0
pandas                             0.25.3
pandas-profiling                   2.5.3

Comment: Please provide more details about the python version and. packages' versions you are using

Comment: Missing python3-matplotlib ? ... pip list | grep -E "matplotlib|pandas" should be `pip3 list | grep -E "matplotlib|pandas"`

Answer (score 8):

I don't know the actual reason but I restarted the kernel and it is working.

Before restarting the kernel I executed following commands:

> conda install -c anaconda pandas-profiling

Comment: I don't know the actual reason either, but in my case updating `pip install --upgrade pandas numpy matplotlib` fixed it.