# How to Import Pandas Profiling

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-profiling

I installed pandas-profiling by I cannot import it in Jupyter Notebook. This is the last part of the long import error I get.

> ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting when the default backend "matplotlib" is selected.

Any ideas on how I can import it?

Comment: Try to restart kernel once - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60977789/importerror-matplotlib-is-required-for-plotting-when-the-default-backend-matpl

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I am only 4 weeks into learning python and am working on my first big project for class. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Okay then i am marking it as duplicate. I am glade it helped.